# Print log to terminal running artisan serve

Tags: laravel

I am trying to debug my application and I had few log statements using `Log` facade. For now, I run the application using `artisan serve` and it will write the log message to the log file and to get a real time log message I run.

```
tail -f laravel.log
```

Is there any way I can directly print the log message to the same console/terminal that is running `php artisan serve`?

Answer (score 21):

You can do this using following. This works anywhere..

```
$output = new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();
$output->writeln("<info>Error message</info>");
```

This will print the message in terminal / console  that is running `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 20):

```
tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log & php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 10):

Based on @aquasmit answer:

```
$output = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();
$output->writeln("<info>Info message</info>");
```

Note the added `\` before `Symfony`.

Answer (score 5):

The standard "error_log" PHP function does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log using facade like this:

```php
Log::info('Hi there!');
```

Consider using `errorlog` channel:

```bash
# .env file
LOG_CHANNEL=errorlog
```