# console log api request Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to know does it is possible to console log from backEnd API i mean incoming post request from mobile app.

my controller looks like this:

```
//Inspector writes notes
public function inspectorNotes(Request $request){
    try{
        //return response()->json($request->all());
        error_log(print_r($request->all(), true));
        die();
        $note = new damageNotes();
        $note->damageId     =   $request->damageid;
        $note->inspectorId  =   Auth::user()->id;
        $note->note         =   $request->note;
        $note->images       =   $request->image;
        $note->save();
        return response()->json(['response'=>'Note has been saved']);
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        return response()->json(['response'=>$e->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

i use error_log(print_r($request->all(), true)); to console api but this works only in my machine when i try incoming request from another device doesn't show something.
Note: I'm working with laravel framework.

Comment: Look at this post. It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510225/print-log-to-terminal-running-artisan-serve

Comment: which Laravel version do you use? Why don't you try with Monolog library? http://github.com/seldaek/monolog

Comment: thank you the Monolog library it works.